# Fhir , slicing based on the value of an extension

Tags: hl7-fhir

is there a way to define a slicing based on the value of an extension on top of each element of a collection? example: Procedure.bodySite

```xml
    <element id="Procedure.bodySite">
      <path value="Procedure.bodySite" />
      <slicing>
        <discriminator>
          <type value="value" />
          <path value="bodySite.extension(&quot;http://a/ext&quot;).value" />
        </discriminator>
        <rules value="open" />
      </slicing>
    </element>
    <element id="Procedure.bodySite.extension">
      <path value="Procedure.bodySite.extension" />
      <slicing>
        <discriminator>
          <type value="value" />
          <path value="url" />
        </discriminator>
        <rules value="open" />
      </slicing>
    </element>
    <element id="Procedure.bodySite.extension:myExtension">
      <path value="Procedure.bodySite.extension" />
      <sliceName value="myExtension" />
      <type>
        <code value="Extension" />
        <profile value="http://a/ext" />
      </type>
    </element>
    <element id="Procedure.bodySite:sliceBodySite">
      <path value="Procedure.bodySite" />
      <sliceName value="sliceBodySite" />
      <max value="1" />
    </element>
    <element id="Procedure.bodySite:sliceBodySite.text">
      <path value="Procedure.bodySite.extension" />
      <fixedBoolean value="true" />
    </element>
```

the result is : Unable to resolve discriminator in definitions: bodySite.extension('http://a/ext').value

so what is the problem here?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "on top of each element of a collection"?

Comment: for example, I've added an extension on each CodeableConcept from Procedure.bodySite collection which contains only a boolean value. now i'm gonna make a slicing based on that boolean value, is it possible? i see almost every examples used the existing properties such as text as discriminator, but none of them used extensions

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.extension("url")` as part of the path in a discriminator.  So you can slice by value with a discriminator path of:
`bodySite.extension("http://your/extension/url/here").value`

Comment: would you please check the updated question again?